# Assigning Unique Callback Functions in Elm

Tags: function, svg, callback, elm

I am trying to make a simple Elm webapp that lets me add rectangles to an SVG canvas and drag them around. However, I am running into problems trying to programmatically differentiate the rectangle click handlers. The below code works fine for a single rectangle (mousedown on the shape and move around and it will drag correctly). However, every further rectangle generated somehow has its mousedown function *also* specifying the first rectangle.

This creates the rectangle with rectID and (I thought) would also create a *unique* partial function of customOnMouseDown with the rectID parameter of *this* rectangle.

```
    NewRect rectId ->
        let
            newRect =
                Rect (customOnMouseDown (String.fromInt rectId)) (String.fromInt rectId)
                    (rectId) 0 20 20
        in
            ( { model |
                    rects = newRect :: model.rects
              , count = model.count + 1}
            , Cmd.none)
```

After trying several different formulations, I think my mental model of Elm's runtime is wrong, so I would like to not only know the correct way to do this sort of thing but also why this way isn't working, if possible.

Full code:

```
import Browser
import Browser.Events
import Html exposing (..)
import Html.Events
import Task
import Time
import Svg exposing (..)
import Svg.Attributes exposing (..)
import Svg.Events exposing (..)
import Random
import Json.Decode as D

-- MAIN

-- main =
main =
  Browser.element
    { init = init
    , view = view
    , update = update
    , subscriptions = subscriptions
    }

-- MODEL


type alias Model =
    { drag : Maybe Drag
    , pos : Position
    , rects : List Rect 
    , selected : String
    , count : Int
    }

type alias Position =
    { x: Int
    , y: Int
    }

type alias Drag =
    { startPos : Position
    , currentPos : Position 
    }

type alias Rect =
    { mouseDown : Html.Attribute Msg
    , rectId : String
    , x : Int
    , y : Int
    , width : Int
    , height : Int
    }

init : () -> (Model, Cmd Msg)
init _ =
  ( Model Nothing (Position 0 0) [] "" 0
  , Cmd.none
  )


-- UPDATE


type Msg
  =  Press Position String 
  | Release Position 
  | Move Position
  | AddRect
  | NewRect Int


update : Msg -> Model -> (Model, Cmd Msg)
update msg model =
  case msg of
    Press pos rectId ->
        ({model | drag = Just (Drag pos pos)
         , selected = rectId
        }
        , Cmd.none)

    Release pos ->
        ({ model | drag = Nothing, selected = ""}, Cmd.none)

    Move pos ->
        ( { model |
                rects =
                case (getRect model.selected model.rects) of
                    Nothing -> model.rects
                    Just r ->
                        (Rect r.mouseDown r.rectId pos.x pos.y 20 20)::(dropRect r.rectId model.rects)
              }
            , Cmd.none )

    AddRect ->
        ( model
        , Random.generate NewRect (Random.int 1 1000)
        )
    NewRect rectId ->
        let
            newRect =
                Rect (customOnMouseDown (String.fromInt rectId)) (String.fromInt rectId)
                    (rectId) 0 20 20
        in
            ( { model |
                    rects = newRect :: model.rects
              , count = model.count + 1}
            , Cmd.none)

-- SUBSCRIPTIONS

subscriptions : Model -> Sub Msg
subscriptions model =
    case model.drag of
    Nothing ->
      Sub.none

    Just _ ->
      Sub.batch [ Browser.Events.onMouseMove mouseMoveDecoder
                , Browser.Events.onMouseUp mouseReleaseDecoder ]

mouseMoveDecoder : D.Decoder Msg 
mouseMoveDecoder =
    D.map Move mouseCoordDecoder


mouseReleaseDecoder : D.Decoder Msg 
mouseReleaseDecoder =
    D.map Release mouseCoordDecoder


mouseCoordDecoder : D.Decoder Position 
mouseCoordDecoder =
    D.map2 Position
         (D.field "x" D.int)
         (D.field "y" D.int)

-- VIEW


view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
  let
      total_width = "1000"
      total_height = "500"
  in 
  div []
  [ svg
    [ width total_width
    , height total_height
    , viewBox ("0 0 " ++ total_width ++ total_height)
    ]
    (renderShape  model.rects)

  , div [] [ div [] [ Html.text (String.fromInt model.pos.x) ]
           , div [] [ Html.text (String.fromInt model.pos.y) ]
           , div [] [ Html.text  model.selected ]
           , div [] [ Html.text (String.fromInt (List.length  model.rects)) ]
           , div [] [ (renderList (List.map .rectId  model.rects)) ]

           , button [ onClick AddRect ] [ Html.text "Rect" ] ]
  ]

renderList : List String -> Html msg
renderList lst =
    ul []
        (List.map (\l -> li [] [ Html.text l ]) lst)


customOnMouseDown : String -> (Html.Attribute Msg)
customOnMouseDown shapeIndex =
    let
        decoder = 
            D.oneOf
                [ D.map2
                      Press 
                      ( D.map2
                            Position 
                            ( D.field "pageX" D.int) 
                            ( D.field "pageY" D.int) 
                      )
                      (D.succeed ( shapeIndex ))
                , D.succeed (Press ( Position 500 500 ) shapeIndex )
                ]  
    in
        Html.Events.on "mousedown" decoder

extractRect : Rect -> Svg Msg
extractRect r =
    rect [ r.mouseDown
         , x (String.fromInt r.x)
         , y (String.fromInt r.y)
         , width (String.fromInt r.width)
         , height (String.fromInt r.height)
         ]
    []

renderShape : List Rect -> List (Svg Msg)
renderShape lst =
    List.map extractRect lst

rectIdMatch : String -> Rect -> Bool
rectIdMatch target rect = target == rect.rectId

getRect : String -> List Rect -> (Maybe Rect)
getRect target lst =
    List.head (List.filter (rectIdMatch target) lst)

dropRect : String -> List Rect -> List Rect
dropRect target lst =
    case lst of
        [] -> []
        [x] ->
            if x.rectId == target then
                []
            else
                []
        x::xs ->
            if x.rectId == target then
                xs
            else
                x::(dropRect target xs)
```

Comment: It is worth noting that storing functions in your models/messages is generally considered a bad idea in Elm, as it breaks things like the debugger. Generally you are much better off having a data structure that holds the data you are putting into your function and storing that instead, then calling the function in the `view` instead. In general it is best to have a single "source of truth" on each value, and just transform it/pass it around as needed. Your current model stores the same information in different forms a lot, which is an easy way to introduce bugs when they get out of sync.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the concrete change you're suggesting: it seems natural to have the rectangles stored as a list in the model, no?

Comment: Yes, but your `Rect` type contains `mouseDown : Html.Attribute Msg`, which can be generated in the view using the `rectId` attribute instead. Imagine you change the id of the `Rect`, you now have to update the `mouseDown` as well or you have a bug. If you generate it in the view, it can't get out of sync. In concrete terms, it looks like deleting that attribute and changing `extractRect` to use `customOnMouseDown r.rectId` instead of `r.mouseDown`.

Comment: Ah, ok. I think that makes sense. Unfortunately, changing the customOnMouseDown partial function to be generated in the view doesn't change the issue.

Comment: It does when I do it: https://ellie-app.com/76K6JmDJg4Fa1

Comment: Interesting - so apparently changing the customOnMouseDown to remove the D.oneOf solved the issue (with both formulations of generated the partial function in the update or the view).
Clearly I didn't understand the JSON decoder formulation when I was writing it (although I'm also not sure why it was wrong in this way). Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Per glennsl https://ellie-app.com/76K6JmDJg4Fa1][1](https://ellie-app.com/76K6JmDJg4Fa1)

Changing the JSON decoder seemed to fix the issue, although I'm not sure why

```
customOnMouseDown : String -> (Html.Attribute Msg)
customOnMouseDown shapeIndex =
    let
        decoder = 
            D.oneOf
                [ D.map2
                      Press 
                      ( D.map2
                            Position 
                            ( D.field "pageX" D.int) 
                            ( D.field "pageY" D.int) 
                      )
                      (D.succeed ( shapeIndex ))
                , D.succeed (Press ( Position 500 500 ) shapeIndex )
                ]  
    in
        Html.Events.on "mousedown" decode
```